# How can I calculate mean and variance incrementally?

Tags: aggregation, variance

Say I have a set S of values, and want to store in a database some summary information about that set, so that later when I acquire a new value v I can make a reasonable estimate of what the summary information would be about the set S ∪ {v} --- although by now I no longer have access to the original members of S. I'd like the summary information to include the mean and variance of these sets, and as minimal additional information as needed. A natural idea for the additional information would be S's cardinality. But I'm willing to save more complicated information about S if needed. My main constraint is to minimize the size of the retained information.

If I only cared about the mean of the sets, then storing the mean plus cardinality of S would obviously be enough. I could update with a new value by just taking a weighted average of the old mean (times the old cardinality) and the new value. But I'd like to be able to keep track of the variance of the sets too. A good estimate is enough; I don't need to be able to reconstruct what the exact mean and variance of S ∪ {v} would be.

I expect that even asking this displays how naive I am about statistics, but I'd appreciate any help. I don't know where to look for answers.

Comment: Would [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponentially_weighted_moving_variance_and_standard_deviation) give what I'm looking for?

Comment: This problem was discussed, with proof and some alternate methods over on https://math.stackexchange.com. (Copied from answer by [Richmond Newman](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/43578/richmond-newman))

Answer (score 4):

Following that link about moving variance in my comment, I came upon this: [Welford's online algorithm for calculating variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm), which seems to supply what I'm looking for.

Here's the algorithm:

```
new_count = old_count + 1
d1 = new_value - old_mean
new_mean = old_mean + d1/new_count
d2 = new_value - new_mean
new_sum_squares = old_sum_squares + d1*d2
```

From a saved `(count, mean, sum_squares)`, the population variance can be computed as `sum_squares/count`.

Given an initial value `v`, one can start with:

```
count = 1
mean = v
sum_squares = 0
```

If you want a weighted mean and variance, you can modify the algorithm like this:

```
new_count = old_count + new_weight
d1 = (new_value - old_mean)*new_weight
```

The other lines stay the same. (Here the mean of values `a,b` with weights `x,y`, respectively, is `(ax+by)/(x+y)`; and the weighted sum_squares is `x(a-mean)^2 + y(b-mean)^2`.)

Answer (score 4):

This problem was discussed, with proof and some alternate methods over on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102978/incremental-computation-of-standard-deviation).

Comment: After further reading, I might also warn that some of the methods there (while correct mathematically) may pose numerical stability issues due to large numbers of multiplications/divisions and accumulated rounding errors.  I would probably favor the method given in that discussion by [mjqxxxx](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/102982/510230)